# Acyclicity of Flasque sheaves without A.C.

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I say that a sheaf on a space X, is flasque if the restriction maps are surjective, that is any local section extend to a global section.

Now it is a fact that if $F_1$ is flasque and if $0 \to F_1 \to F_2 \to F_3 \to 0$ is an exact sequence of sheaves on X, then it remains exact taking global section. This come down to prove that for any cover of X the $H^1$ of F subordinate to that cover is trivial.

To prove this last step you can use a well ordering of the cover, and then is pretty easy. So i was wondering: is it possible to prove this statement without using the well ordering axiom?

Thanks

Comment: I would answer, but I could never understand the notion of sheaves.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: But maybe you know the answer of the following special case? (Coming from the case where $X$ is discrete): Suppose we have a family of surjective homomorphisms $\varphi_i: A_i\to B_i$ of abelian groups. Is $\prod_i A_i\to \prod_i B_i$ necessarily surjective without AC?

Comment: @Hanno: Well, if the $\varphi_i$ are already given, isn't it already obvious?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I might be in brainless-mode today, but why is it obvious? Don't you need to *choose* a preimage in $A_i$ for every single component of an element of $\prod_i B_i$?

Comment: @Hanno: Well, surjectivity is not the same as having a section. Yeah, it's obviously not provable that there is no inverse to the surjection.

Comment: @Asaf I'm also not sure about your "obvious" statement.  What if each $A_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and each $\varphi_i$ is the canonical surjection onto $B_i = \mathbb{Z}_2$?  (Note that this canonical surjection does not depend on the choice of isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}$.)  To show that $(1,1,\ldots)$ is in the range of $\prod_i \varphi_i$ is equivalent to showing that we can choose an isomorphism $A_i \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for each $i$, which might be impossible, right?

Comment: @Mimmo Trying to do any kind of derived functor cohomology without the axiom of choice is not a good idea. See the first few sections of [Blass, _Cohomology detects failures of the axiom of choice_].

Comment: @Trevor: True, sometimes you don't need the axiom of choice, but there are easy examples. (It's good to see you here!)

Comment: @Asaf Thanks!  My point was that the answer in Hanno's special case seems to be no (even though the family of maps $\varphi_i$ is given) whereas you seem to be saying that the answer is yes.

Comment: @Trevor: Hanno's first comment seemed, to me, to be asking, whether or not there is a surjection. Only in the second comment it was clarified that the question is about a section.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not sure if I interpret Hanno's second comment as changing the question.  But in any case, it seems to me that we still disagree about the answer to the question that was asked literally in Hanno's first comment: is the product of the surjections necessarily a surjection?  You say it obviously is a surjection, and I give an example where I claim that it is *not* a surjection.

Comment: @Asaf My example is based on a simpler example in the category of sets.  If each $A_i$ has cardinality $2$ and each $B_i$ is a singleton then there is a (unique) family of surjections $\varphi_i : A_i \to B_i$.  But without $\mathsf{AC}$, we might have $\prod_i A_i = \emptyset$, in which case there is no surjection $\prod_i A_i \to \prod_i B_i$ at all, right?

Comment: @Trevor: Can you show me a ring which has more than isomorphism with $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Asaf No, but every abelian group that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly two isomorphisms with $\mathbb{Z}$, and Hanno asked about abelian groups.

Comment: @Trevor: I see your point,  and I should have read better. Yeah, you're probably right that this is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about sheaves, but I can give a "no" answer to what Hanno mentions in his comment as a special case.

Namely, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are families of abelian groups $(A_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$ and $(B_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$ and a family of maps $(\varphi_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$ such that each $\varphi_i$ is a surjective homomorphism, but the product homomorphism $\prod_i \varphi_i : \prod_i A_i \to \prod_i B_i$ is not surjective.

First, note that there is such an example in the category of sets.  (Then we will modify this example to involve abelian groups.)  Let $(S_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$ be a family of sets of cardinality $2$ for which there is no choice function (a family of "pairs of socks", in Russell's analogy.)  Let $\varphi_i$ denote the unique surjection $S_i \to \{0\}$. Then $\prod_i \varphi_i$ is not a surjection $ \prod_i S_i \to \prod_i \{0\}$.  (In this example there can be no such surjection at all because $\prod_i S_i$ is empty and $\prod_i \{0\}$ is not.)

Now we can define, for each $i$, an infinite cyclic group whose generators are the elements of $S_i$.  To do this, define $A_i$ to be the abelian group generated by $S_i$ satisfying the two (equivalent) relations saying that the elements of $S_i$ are negatives of each other.  Then $A_i \cong \mathbb{Z}$ but choosing such an isomorphism is equivalent to choosing an element of $S_i$.

Let $\varphi_i$ denote the unique surjective homomorphism $A_i \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Then the element $(1,1,\ldots) \in \prod_i \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not in the range of $\prod_i \varphi_i$: if $\varphi_i(n_i) = 1$ for all $i$, then $n_i \ne 0$ for all $i$; define $s_i \in S_i$ to be the unique generator of $A_i$ such that $n_i$ is a positive multiple of $s_i$.  Then $(s_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$ is a choice function for $\prod_i S_i$, a contradiction.

It seems likely to me that this argument has already appeared somewhere in the literature, in which case I would appreciate a reference.